# Make a Histogram in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

We use the [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) library in our codebase and I need to create a histogram, which is not one of their default chart types. So I'm attempting to override the x-axis tick marks on a bar chart so that they appear at the left and right corners of each bar instead of directly underneath.

In the below example I've gotten the x-axis how I want it by adding an extra item in the `labels` array and displaying a second x-axis in the `options`. But, because there's now an extra label, the bars are taking up 4/5ths of the width, leaving space for a non-existent data point.

Is there some way that I can specify to ignore the missing data point? Or offset the bars? Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

The [documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) is a little hard to parse through, so I'm not sure if there's something simple I'm missing.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Group A',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5],
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        display: false,
        barPercentage: 1.30,
      }, {
        display: true,
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero:true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
canvas { max-width: 200px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="20" height="20"></canvas>
```

Edit: I realize there are other libraries that could achieve something similar and I am looking into other options. But, I've posted this just in case someone out there knows of a solution via Chart.js, which would be ideal.

Here's an example of what the end result I'm going for is:

[image]

Comment: Is there any motivation for sticking to 1 library? I mean why not write a component that does exactly what you want instead of wrestling with something that was not designed for. Btw a quick google search yields that someone already tried to achieve that using the library you mentioned: https://jsfiddle.net/s8qas3km/17/

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcin I'm also looking at solutions in other libraries, but we'd ideally stick to chart.js because it'd be visually consistent, it's responsive, and the file size of our built app would be smaller with just one library. I've seen that example and it, unfortunately, doesn't meet my requirements. I need the numbers of the x-axis to be on the left and right of the bars, to indicate that any value in that range would go towards that bar's count.

Comment: I see. If you want to get the range, that implementation won't do either. You need to calculate each bin and keep the numbers in memory until you render to DOM. I have a library for that, it internally keeps track of what the ranges (shows on hover rather than the tick mark). Looks like this: https://bl.ocks.org/ibrahimtanyalcin/c2213de41fbc968b210ad6a8aae77a0f     I'm very busy at the moment, I don't have the time to modify to add config to change the tick mark, but if you want to change it go ahead.

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcin The data in my example represents the count for each bin, so the chart looks like how I want it except for the fact that space is being provided for an empty, fifth bar. And yeah I’ve looked at d3 as a solution, but it wouldn’t be ideal (see my last comment).

Comment: which chart, the chart.js chart?

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcin yes the chart in my post

Comment: Ok, I see. Although it's mathematically impossible to guarantee for a distribution with a given bin interval to NOT contain any empty bin, that's entirely function of  the binsize and the dataset. Anyway best of luck.

Comment: build it with another library - spent the past hour trying using various apis for chart - would recommend you using svg or a third-party library. - the time development to hack this isn't worth the resource saving

Comment: @DenisTsoi, thanks for your time. I'm looking into other options yeah, but hopefully someone can come up with a solution via chart.js as that would be ideal.

Comment: if you start messing within the xaxis default settings, you get som resemblance of a histogram, but the problem is where you can’t actually offset the labels (and you can’t use margin/padding to shift the xaxis). Each node/bar corresponds to a “value” unless you create bins/buckets on the fly, like the example in the comments...

Comment: Unfortunately I do not understand your task now. Would you like to add a picture on which you draw what you want to have in end point, please. Please use a screenshot of your example and draw on it.

Comment: @Bharata I've added a picture of the end result I'm trying to achieve

Comment: @thanksd you can check this example https://jsfiddle.net/s8qas3km/17/

Comment: @thanksd, unfortunately it is like always: I ask something what very important is and others use the information for me and earn for this points :-(

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe you can get the result you want by using the `max` parameter on the `ticks` configuration of the x axes.

By using 2 different x axes with different maximums you can label the bars differently from how they're drawn. Resulting in labeling the marks in between the bars without drawing an extra "empty" bar.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var dataValues = [12, 19, 3, 5];
var dataLabels = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: dataLabels,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Group A',
      data: dataValues,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        display: false,
        barPercentage: 1.3,
        ticks: {
            max: 3,
        }
     }, {
        display: true,
        ticks: {
            autoSkip: false,
            max: 4,
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero:true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
canvas { max-width: 200px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="20" height="20"></canvas>
```

Comment: Boom! That's exactly what I was looking for, some way to limit the number of bars. Thank you!

Comment: It is very important to note that the 'max: 3' and 'max: 4' are the ACTUAL values in the labels data. I struggled to find out that for long time in case anyone in same position.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean, if you aren't incrementing by units of one you'll need to take that into account, yes. Those are values on the x axis not an index.

Comment: My indentation is correct in the edit version of this answer, this seems to be a bug in Stack Overflow? dunno what's going on there

Comment: adding an extra tab (4 spaces) before the code fixed things, how strange....