# How to offset the legends of the bars in a "chart.js" bar chart?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I'm trying to get the labels of the x-axis in the bar chart to NOT be positioned directly under each bar (which is default setting) but instead stand in the left / right side of the bars. As it is preferred when drawing a histogram. The left and right label of each bar would then be the interval for that bar.

I found out from the documentation it has something to do with the property grid:{offset:true} that I should apply to the x-axis, but the code isn't working for me. The labels are still directly underneath each bar.

[Documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#offsetgridlines)

What am I doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated!

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Number of Arrivals',
      data: [19, 28, 20, 16, 50, 65, 58],
      backgroundColor: 'green',
    }]},
  options: {    
    scales: {
              xAxes: [{
                display: false, 
                ticks: {max: 10,}, 
                grid: {offset: true}},
                {
                display: true, 
                ticks: {autoSkip: false, max: 10,}, 
                grid: {offset: true}
              }],
                yAxes: [{
                ticks: {beginAtZero: false}
              }]
            }
    
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.2.0/chart.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<h1>The select element</h1>

<canvas id="canvas" aria-label="Canvas with graph" role="img"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason you can't get it to work is because you use the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51880101/make-a-histogram-in-chart-js), which is written for version 2.7, and you are using version 3.2. There are many breaking changes with version 3, including many different names in the options.

I couldn't get it working either, but it should be easily possible with a 3.x version.

[Here's a link to a GitHub post including a jsfiddle link.](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3900#issuecomment-842541723)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate it.